# Is it possible to mix Unity with UIKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, unity-game-engine

For example if you have a UIKit-based app is it possible to include a "Unity view" in a small portion of the screen for a special effect or does use of Unity exclude UIKit from an app?

Comment: here is a plugin may match your need http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/188912-iOS-Bridge-Unity-with-UIKit